# TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript - TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)

Tags: node.js, typescript, server, yarn-workspaces

when I run `yarn start` the server gives me the following error, I have tried to fix it in package.json and tsconfig.json, but still not working

```
xxxxxxxxxxx/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:423
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/startServer.ts:63:7 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ store: RateLimitRedisStore; windowMs: number; max: number; delayMs: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Options'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'delayMs' does not exist in type 'Options'.

63       delayMs: 0 // disable delaying - full speed until the max limit is reached
         ~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: It work for me:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74617912/tserror-%e2%a8%af-unable-to-compile-typescript